# SQL Server Current Date compare with specific date

Tags: sql-server

I got 1 table which is dbo.Invoice. My current query now is able to select "SalesRef" that does not have invoice for "Mvt_Type" = '122'. However, I need to extend my query with PostDate field.

My problem is current query still display an SalesRef that does not have invoice for "Mvt_Type" = '122' with Postdate today( 8/8/2017). My expected result is it can only be display if no invoice was made more than 2 days after the Postdate. So, it suppose to display on 11/8/2017 or more.

Table dbo.Invoice

```
| PO_NUMBER     | TYPE  | MVT_TYPE  | QUANTITY  | SALESREF  | DEBIT     | POSTDATE      |
|-----------    |------ |---------- |---------- |---------- |-------    |------------   |
| 10001001      | GR    | 101       | 1000.00   | 5001      | S         | 2017-01-08    |
| 10001001      | GR    | 101       | 2000.00   | 5002      | S         | 2017-02-08    |
| 10001001      | GR    | 122       | 1000.00   | 5001      | H         | 2017-01-08    |
| 10001001      | INV   | 000       | 1000.00   | 5001      | S         | 2017-01-08    |
| 10001001      | INV   | 000       | 2000.00   | 5002      | S         | 2017-02-08    |
| 10001001      | GR    | 122       | 1500.00   | 5002      | H         | 2017-02-08    |
| 10001001      | INV   | 000       | 1000.00   | 5001      | H         | 2017-01-08    |
```

Below is my current query :

```
  SELECT * 
FROM dbo.INVOICE i 
WHERE MVT_TYPE = '122' AND SALESREF IS NOT NULL AND POSTDATE > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,2,getdate()),101) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM dbo.INVOICE 
WHERE DEBIT = 'H' AND  MVT_TYPE = '000' AND SALESREF = i.SALESREF )
```

Expected Result is same like below. But this time need to add PostDate.

```
| PO_NUMBER     | TYPE  | MVT_TYPE  | QUANTITY  | SALESREF  | DEBIT     | POSTDATE      |
|-----------    |------ |---------- |---------- |---------- |-------    |------------   |
| 10001001      | GR    | 122       | 1500.00   | 5002      | H         | 2017-02-08    |
```

Comment: This question isn't clear. Can you please explain more what the problem is? Specifically, it isn't clear what you mean by "extend my query with selection date".

Comment: Safwan, can you please edit your question and show us the expected result? and be specific if you have a problem with your query.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Updated

Comment: @Sami Updated. Hope you can understand it

Comment: What is the type of PostDate?

Comment: @sepupic varchar

Comment: That is the problem, varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PostDate is DATE or DATETIME, instead of casting you could use `DATEDIFF` function to get the days between two dates and do the INT comparison:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, PostDate, GETDATE())>2
```

If PostDate is varchar, stored in the format shown in the OP:

```
SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT ....
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(PostDate as datetime), GETDATE())>2
```

**EDIT:** Apparently DATEDIFF will work if PostDate is VARCHAR data type as well

```
DECLARE @PostDate VARCHAR(50)

SET @PostDate='08-01-2017'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @PostDate, GETDATE()) -- GETDATE() is 08-08-2017

-- Returns 7
```

Having said this, it is a good practice to keep Dates and Times as proper data types. In your case, you could change the data type to DATE, if possible. Will speed up lookups

**EDIT 2:** Please note, SQL Server works with ISO 8601 Date Format, which is YYYY-MM-DD, but the dates in OP's example, even though as per OP refer to dates in August 2017, are given incorrectly (referring to Jan and Feb 2017) and are stored as varchar. For correct results, these need to be either converted to DATE/DATETIME data type, or reformatted with the correct ISO format.

**EDIT 3:** Showing an example of casting OP's date format into proper, ISO format before calling `DATEDIFF`:

```
SET LANGUAGE british

DECLARE @PostDate VARCHAR(50)

SET @PostDate='2017-01-08'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(@PostDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) -- GETDATE() is 08-08-2017

-- Returns 7
```

And the `WHERE` clause would be as follows:

-- In the begining of the select statement

```
SET LANGUAGE british

SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(PostDate as datetime), GETDATE())>2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it right as expected result. Thank you very much Dimitri.

Comment: No, DATEDIFF will do conversion internally. I'll update my answer to show an example

Comment: You changed the format of date stored in his table, his format is yyyy-dd-mm, so if you try your code with SET @PostDate='2017-02-08' you'll get 181, not 7

Comment: SQL Server works off of ISO 8601 Date format which is YYYY-MM-DD. The date in your example is February 8th, 2017 and yes, it would have resulted in that many days.

Comment: @Dimitri, '2017-02-08'  is not what I *want* to pass in, but it's a data format that is used in OP's table. And that is his problem

Comment: So was that the reason for a downvote? Would DATEDIFF not have resulted in a correct outcome assuming all dates were in a correct format?

Comment: Yes it gives me incorrect result. If you want I can append a picture to my answer showing it. Or just try to change SET LANGUAGE us_english and run your code with OP's date  '2017-02-08'

Comment: @Dimitri If you change your answer that it will give me the correct result, be sure I'll upvote it

Comment: @Dimitri >>>assuming all dates were in a correct format<<< You should not assume, you should accept the input as it is. It's cleare there would be no problem at all if it was DATE column or at least ISO-representation of a date as a string

Comment: You should at least point out the shortcomings and suggest a better solution, which in this case would be to convert the column data type to datetime or any variationn of it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the POSTDATE - date column? If no then you are comparing strings and the result is as expected as `'2017-01-08' > '08/10/2017' ('2' > '0')`. Most probably you just need to cast the POSTDATE. See the example:

```
select
case
when '2017-01-08'  > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,2,getdate()),101) THEN 1
ELSE 0
end without_cast,
case
when CAST('2017-01-08' AS DATE) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,2,getdate()),101) THEN 1
ELSE 0
end with_cast
```

[image]

So what you need is:

```
  SELECT * 
FROM dbo.INVOICE i 
WHERE MVT_TYPE = '122' AND SALESREF IS NOT NULL AND CAST(POSTDATE AS DATE) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,2,getdate()),101) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM dbo.INVOICE 
WHERE DEBIT = 'H' AND  MVT_TYPE = '000' AND SALESREF = i.SALESREF )
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes, im using string for date but I dont see how it can compare with current date.

Comment: I showed it in "with_cast" section. However I just modified the answer and provided modified query for you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I get no result as my expected result. It suppose to display as expected result since if we compare today date with Postdate = 2/8/2017 , there are difference about 6 days and it is more than 2 days.

Comment: Huh... Then you have logical error. You are comparing the date in the past and say that it is supposed to be greater than the date in the future. It is impossible. Switch ">" to "<".

Comment: @Dmitrij Kultasev, I said him the same thing. From the OP seems he wants dates starting with 20170811 if today is 20170808, but then we approved the answer that returns dates that are less than today

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you store a `date` as a `varchar`.

To compare 2 dates correctly you should compare their DATE rappresentation, not strings.

So I suggest you to convert your varchar to date, i.e. instead of
     `CAST(POSTDATE AS DATE) > CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,2,getdate()),101)`

you should use `DATEFROMPARTS ( left(POSTDATE, 4), right(POSTDATE, 2), substring(POSTDATE,6,2))  > dateadd(day,2,cast(getdate() as date));`.

[DATEFROMPARTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228(v=sql.110).aspx) function is available starting with SQL Server 2012, let me know if you are on the earlier version and I'll rewrite my code

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'm using SQL SERVER 17. I already test your query above. It seem no result appear after execute the query.

Comment: @Safwan, it depends on the format of your strings. Is it yyyy-dd-mm as shown in your original post?

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is a logic error in your code. Your code now filters for the POSTDATE greater than today by 2 days. So if you have the dates all less than today your query must return nothing

Comment: I'll update my answer with getting date from a sting in another way. But still don't understand if you want to filter POSTDATE to be less og greater than today